# VF page to create a New Case need code to add picklist of Asset Names from Users Account

Tags: visualforce, case, asset

We have a Visualforce page that is creating a New Case using a limited number of fields for the user to complete before submitting the Case.

This page can only be accessed after the user logs in to our Community, so they are a logged in Community user.

We need a picklist in the apex:form that will show the User a list of the Assets on their Account.

I am lost on how to get that list onto my existing form.  I have the rest of the fields I need working just fine.

It seems I will need to find out who my User is and get their Account or User id and use that to get the list of their Assets and then output that list into an apex:selectList possibly and then of course insert the chosen Asset back into the Users New Case.

Here is the updated VF page minus the CSS after Answers

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="myWeb2CaseExtension" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false"
           applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0">
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<title>XYZ</title>  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" />    

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <header>
    <apex:image url="{!$Resource.Logo}" alt="Logo" width="200" height="67" id="logo" />
<ul>
  <li><a href="{!$Page.MyCases}">My Cases</a></li>
  <li><a href="#home">My Assets</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">My Account</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Knowledge</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">Discussions</a></li>
</ul>
  </header>
  <div class="sidebar1">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link one</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link two</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>

    <aside>
      <p> Aliquam erat eu id est. Integer ac vestibulum metus. Integer ac vestibulum metus. Integer ac vestibulum metus. 
          Aliquam erat eu id est.Integer ac vestibulum metus. Aliquam erat eu id est.  
          Integer ac vestibulum metus. Aliquam erat eu id est.
        </p>
</aside>
  <!-- end .sidebar1 --></div>
  <article class="content">
<section>

<h2>Create a New Case</h2>

<h3>Please enter the case information</h3>

<apex:form >

<apex:messages id="error" styleClass="errorMsg" layout="table" style="margin-top:1em;"/>

<table>
            <tr>
                <td class="tdtop"><span class="formLabels">Asset</span></td>
                <td>    
                        <apex:selectList value="{!Case.Asset.Name}" size="7" >
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!assetOptions}" />
                        </apex:selectList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="formLabels">Subject</span></td>
                <td><apex:inputField styleClass="subjectSize" value="{!Case.Subject}"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="formLabels">Priority</span></td>
                <td><apex:inputField value="{!Case.Priority}"/></td>
            </tr>    
            <tr>
                <td class="tdtop"><span class="formLabels">Description</span></td>
                <td><apex:inputField styleClass="descriptionSize" required="true" value="{!Case.Description}"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="formLabels">System Outage</span></td>
                <td><apex:inputField value="{!Case.Outage__c}"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="formLabels">Data Loss</span></td>
                <td><apex:inputField value="{!Case.Data_Loss__c}"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><apex:commandButton action="{!saveCase}" value="Send Your Case To Support"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

</apex:form>      


</section>
    <section> </section>
    <!-- end .content --></article>
  <footer>
    <p>Support Community</p>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Terms of use</a></li>
      <li>Copyright © 2015 XYZ, Inc., All Rights Reserved</li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
  <!-- end .container -->
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

Here is My current controller extension

```
     public class myWeb2CaseExtension {
    public Case webcase {get;set;}
    public SelectOption[] assetOptions {get;set;} 

    public myWeb2CaseExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {

        webcase = (Case) stdController.getRecord();

        User[] users = [SELECT ContactId FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
        User usr = users[0];

        Contact[] contacts = [SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Id = :usr.ContactId];

        if (contacts.isEmpty()) {
            // handle when contacts is empty
        } else {
            Contact cont = contacts[0];
            Asset[] assets = [SELECT Name, ContactId, AccountId FROM Asset WHERE AccountId = :cont.AccountId];
            assetOptions = new SelectOption[] {};
            //if you want people to be able to choose no asset do this
            assetOptions.add(new SelectOption('None', 'None'));

            for (Asset asst: assets) {
                assetOptions.add(new SelectOption(asst.Id, asst.Name));                
            } 
        }
    }
    public PageReference saveCase() {
        try {
            Database.DMLOptions dmlOpts = new Database.DMLOptions();
            dmlOpts.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = true;
            webcase.setOptions(dmlOpts);
            webcase.Origin = 'Web';
            insert(webcase);
        } catch (System.DMLException e) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            return null;
        }
        PageReference p = Page.MyCases;
        p.setRedirect(true);
        return p;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a rough sequence of queries you'd need to do this:

```
User[] users = [SELECT ContactId,IsPortalEnabled FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
User usr = users[0];

Contact[] contacts = [SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Id = :usr.ContactId];
Contact cont = contacts[0];

Asset[] assets = [SELECT Name, ContactId, AccountId, Description, Name, Quantity, Price FROM Asset WHERE AccountId = :cont.AccountId];
```

Note, I see there are both `ContactId` and `AccountId` fields on Asset - make sure you aren't supposed to get the assets directly from contact.

From here, you need to build a `SelectOptions` list. You can use something like this:

```
//Declare this at the top of your controller with a getter 
SelectOption[] assetOptions {get;set;}

//after you have your Asset list, do this
assetOptions = new SelectOption[]{};
//if you want people to be able to choose no asset do this
assetOptions.add(new SelectOption('', ''));

for (Asset asst : assets) {
    assetOptions.add(asst.Id, asst.Name);
}
```

Finally, your select options on a page looks like:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!case.Your_Case_Asset_Field__c}" size="1" >
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!assetOptions}" />
</apex:selectList>
```

**Note** There is no error check code in this example. Make sure you add that.

Comment: I will try this code out tomorrow

Comment: Should the second one be 
Contact[] contacts = [SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE ContactId = :usr.ContactId];
Contact cont = contacts[0];

Comment: Yes sorry, that was a bug - fixed.

Comment: I am trying to test this using an Execute Anonymous Window in the Dev Console and get this error
No such column 'ContactId' on entity 'Contact'

Comment: Hmm sorry another bug - make it `Id` instead of `ContactId`

Comment: One more bug. the first line first object Users[] I believe should be User[] I am running this in the Execute Anonymous window and getting error System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0 but i believe this is due to there being an empty list. I will try the code under a different user to verify or work on some empty list code to check this.

Comment: Yes, it's getting an empty list. There is no users[0]. UserInfo.getUserId() is not likely to return anything given that you are running as Anonymous. Login, get your user id and use that - ie, `id='youruserid'` -Oh and yes, fixed the other bug.

Comment: I put this in for empty list checking
if (contacts.isEmpty()) {
  // handle when contacts is empty
} else {
  Contact cont = contacts[0];
    Asset[] assets = [SELECT Name, ContactId, AccountId FROM Asset WHERE AccountId = :cont.AccountId];
}
Sounds crazy but how do i put all of this in the controller extension so I can call the var assets to populate my form selectionList?  Do I need to create a class out of it?

Comment: Added putting this from Assets to SelectOptions

Comment: Where i am lost is how I add this to my Controller. Just copying it in there gives me error "unexpected token : User" and I am not familiar enough with how I can put this into the controller

Comment: Put it after this line: `webcase = (Case)stdController.getRecord();` - ie, in the constructor is fine. It must be in a method and the constructor is good enough for now.

Comment: OK I put the Queries in the Constructor
Now where do I put this stuff where it will work. I tried putting it in the constructor also no luck
//Declare this at the top of your controller with a getter 
SelectOption[] assetOptions {get;set;}

//after you have your Asset list, do this
assetOptions = new SelectOption[]{};
//if you want people to be able to choose no asset do this
assetOptions.add(new SelectOption('', ''));

for (Asset asst : assets) {
    assetOptions.add(asst.Id, asst.Name);
}

Comment: I was also thinking I could just use an <apex:repeat> in the VF page to build the selectList but I do not know how to modify the code to return the variable assets either. So i would need help figuring out this or my previous comment

Comment: Can you please post your most recent code in the question above? I should be able to see what's going wrong.

Comment: ok i put the updated controller extension code in the main question  It is fairly butchered at this point

Comment: Hi, I formatted your controller and made the `Case` object public. This is the object that you are writing to. If it's public, you don't need to do anything special - the standardController will handle everything for you. You need to change `Case` to `webcase` in your `Visualforce` page - this will allow your to actually save your Case (Oh, my edit to your controller code won't appear until it's peer reviewed)

Comment: I was able to view the edit however the code i posted does not work and it was not changed enough to fix it.  I just put the selectOption stuff in the else statement but dont think it works there or something else is wrong  the error is Method does not exist or incorrect signature :[List<System.selectOption>].add(Id,String)

Comment: the error mentioned above is from line 24
assetOptions.add(asst.Id, asst.Name);

Comment: Change it to assetOptions.add(String.valueOf(asst.Id), asst.Name);

Comment: I got the error to go away by changing the line to this
assetOptions.add(new SelectOption(asst.Id, asst.Name));
I am testing to see if it works

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Comment: Now it looks like this line in the VF page is causing an error
<apex:selectOptions value="{!assetOptions}" />
Error = Unknown property 'CaseStandardController.assetOptions'

Comment: It's private - make it public. Here: `SelectOption[] assetOptions {get;set;}` should be `public SelectOption[] assetOptions {get;set;}`

Comment: No. there is no field called webcase.selectOptions. Make it `public` in the controller. And don't change the `standardController` to webcase. It was right before.

Comment: OK I got all of the errors taken care of.  I am viewing via a logged in community user and the select box is there but no Asset Names in the box to select from.  Looking for possible reasons  now

Comment: Ok if i set the ID in the firs query to a specific ID to test it does appear
User[] users = [SELECT ContactId FROM User WHERE Id = '005M0000003FFio'];
Might be a permissions issue I will track this down if I can.
Thank you very much for all of your time on this I would not have gotten to this spot for a long time without your assistance.

Comment: well the ID I am hard coding is the id for the same user I am testing with while they are logged in to the community so maybe it is another issue where it is not getting the ID properly.  I will have to take a step back and relook at everything here unless something sticks out to you

Answer (score 2):

> It seems I will need to find out who my User is and get their Account
> or User id and use that to get the list of their Assets and then
> output that list into an apex:selectList possibly and then of course
> insert the chosen Asset back into the Users New Case.

Yes. You've broken down the problem, and those would be the steps to take. Have you tried searching these ?

**1. Finding the logged in user**

Have a look at the [UserInfo class](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm), there's a static method that will return the UserId of the logged in user (based on the execution context).

**2. Get their Account**

Community users have the `user.ContactId` populated, through that you can find the `AccountId` they belong to.

**3. Etc**

From thereon you were pretty much correct, and I'm going to assume you know how to deal with them or will be able to find sample code by google/documentation yourself :-).

Comment: Do I need to find the logged in user if I can just find their Account using user.ContactId as u mentioned?  Does all of this need to be in the Controller extension and I can use the info via a variable in the Apex code on my VF page?

Comment: I am stuck.  I need help getting to the point of having the list of Assets for the Users Account and I think I can handle it from there.  I have not been able to write or find the code I need beyond a line that I was provided by someone else User MyUser = [select id from user where id = :UserInfo.getUserId()]; And I do not know  if this is even what I need or what I need to use from it to get the info I am looking for.  I am just lost and I realize what I need just not how to do it.

Comment: I am getting closer. This is what I have so far:

User MyUser = [Select Contact.AccountId From User Where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];